# Stop an event from propagating through select menus within a div JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a bit of a problem I am trying to solve. Basically I am trying to bind an event listener to some `select` menus within a div. This is my code (it's pretty much the same for each dropdown)

```
$('#compresult').bind('click', 'a.con_add', function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            console.log('choose this contact');
            $contact_name = $('#comp_staff option:selected').text();
            $contactId = $('#comp_staff option:selected').val();
            $type = 'contact';
            $('#item_name').html(" - " + $contact_name);
            $('#comp_name').val($contact_name);
            $('#comp_id').val($contactId);
            $('#type').val($type);
            $('#apply_tags').show();
            $('#active_tags').show();
            $('#doneBtn').show();
            $('#tag_results').load('pages/ajax/query_tags.php', {'query':'A', 'id':$contactId, 'type':$type});
            $('#active_tags').load('pages/ajax/get_tags.php', {'name': $contact_name, 'id': $contactId, 'type': $type},function(response, status, xhr){});
        });

        //Event Listener for the COLUMNS Dropdown.
        $('#compresult').bind('click', 'a.col_add', function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            console.log('choose this column');
            $column_name = $('#comp_cols option:selected').text();
            $columnId = $('#comp_cols option:selected').val();
            $type = 'column';
            $('#item_name').html(" - " + $column_name);
            $('#comp_name').val($column_name);
            $('#comp_id').val($columnId);
            $('#type').val($type);
            $('#apply_tags').show();
            $('#active_tags').show();
            $('#doneBtn').show();
            $('#tag_results').load('pages/ajax/query_tags.php', {'query':'A', 'id':$columnId, 'type':$type});
            $('#active_tags').load('pages/ajax/get_tags.php', {'name': $column_name, 'id': $columnId, 'type': $type},function(response, status, xhr){});
        });

        //Event Listener for the SUPPLEMENTS Dropdown.
        $('#compresult').bind('click', 'a.sup_add', function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            console.log('choose this Supplement');
            $supplement_name = $('#comp_sups option:selected').text();
            $supplementId = $('#comp_sups option:selected').val();
            $type = 'supplement';
            $('#item_name').html(" - " + $supplement_name);
            $('#comp_name').val($supplement_name);
            $('#comp_id').val($supplementId);
            $('#type').val($type);
            $('#apply_tags').show();
            $('#active_tags').show();
            $('#doneBtn').show();
            $('#tag_results').load('pages/ajax/query_tags.php', {'query':'A', 'id':$supplementId, 'type':$type});
            $('#active_tags').load('pages/ajax/get_tags.php', {'name': $supplement_name, 'id': $supplementId, 'type': $type},function(response, status, xhr){});
        });

        //Event Listener for the PROGRAMMES Dropdown.
        $('#compresult').bind('click', 'a.prog_add', function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            console.log('choose this Programme');
            $programme_name = $('#comp_progs option:selected').text();
            $programmeId = $('#comp_progs option:selected').val();
            $type = 'supplement';
            $('#item_name').html(" - " + $programme_name);
            $('#comp_name').val($programme_name);
            $('#comp_id').val($programmeId);
            $('#type').val($type);
            $('#apply_tags').show();
            $('#active_tags').show();
            $('#doneBtn').show();
            $('#tag_results').load('pages/ajax/query_tags.php', {'query':'A', 'id':$programmeId, 'type':$type});
            $('#active_tags').load('pages/ajax/get_tags.php', {'name': $programme_name, 'id': $programmeId, 'type': $type},function(response, status, xhr){});
        });
```

The problem I am having is that when I click on any of the select menus above within the div the event seems to travel through each element down to the last event handler for the 
`a.prog_add` class. I would like to prevent this from happening. I tried `e.stopPropagation()` but that seems to have no affect.

I'd appreciate any help on this as I'm really at a loss as to what to do next.

Comment: Did you try to return false for stopping propagation?

Comment: Yes that is not working either.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. If you create a jsfiddle, we will be more able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `event.stopPropagation()` says :

> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers, therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false.

This statement should have been updated some time ago to include mention of the `.on(event, selector, handler)` syntax, which is an alternative to `.live()`/`.delegate()` and was introduced at version 1.7.

<strike>Your only option is not to delegate - ie. attach your handlers directly to the elements in question.</strike>

Comment: I would ideally like to do it this way, the only issue being that I create these elements dynamically so they are not on the page when it is first loaded, as a result I'm having difficulty attaching them directly.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it again, you may be able to test `event.delegateTarget == event.currentTarget`. When not equal, the event bubbled and when equal, the event did not bubble.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it pointed it me in the right direction and mentioned the `live()` method which I used in the end to resolve the issue. I know it's been removed since 1.9 but I needed a quick fix and this did the job. Thanks @Roamer-1888

Comment: @Javacadabra, thank you for your generous accept. I've marked up my last sentence with < strike >...< /strike > as you have clearly found a different way.